# How to convert DateTimeComparator to an Ordering[DateTime] in Scala

Tags: scala, jodatime

I just typed this which seems a little ugly:

```
val maxTime = times.max(DateTimeComparator.getInstance().asInstanceOf[Comparator[DateTime]] asScala)
```

`times` is a sequence of org.joda.time.DateTime.

There must be a better way to get that Ordering object for DateTime. Is there?

In particular it'd be great to lose the asInstanceOf ...

Comment: Please refer to [How to define an Ordering in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061141/how-to-define-an-ordering-in-scala)

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use `comparatorToOrdering`:

```
Ordering.comparatorToOrdering(DateTimeComparator.getInstance.asInstanceOf[Comparator[DateTime]])
```

I suppose that's what the `asScala` call does. It's not prettier, I know :-|

(The cast is unfortunately required because `DateTimeComparator` implements `Comparator` as a raw type.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also write your own class that extends the Ordering trait, and use this as input to the maximum function:

```
class JodaDateTimeOrdering extends Ordering[org.joda.time.DateTime] {
  val dtComparer = DateTimeComparator.getInstance()

  def compare(x: DateTime, y: DateTime): Int = {
    dtComparer.compare(x, y)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
times.max(Ordering.fromLessThan[DateTime](
  DateTimeComparator.getInstance.compare(_,_) < 0))
```

which is ugly too!

Where does your `asScala` come from?

*additional thoughts*

I'm not sure there is a better way. `DateComparator` implements *Comparator*.

the `max` method expects an `Ordering[DateTime]`. Ordered and Ordering are invariant in Scala. So I think the case is necessary to use `asScala`.

Comment: asScala is from scalaj.collection, it has a bunch of scala<->java converters

Answer (score 1):

Best possibility, but with additional dependency: [NScala-Time wrapper](https://github.com/nscala-time/) for Joda DateTime has DateTimeOrdering implicit:

https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/nscala_time/time/Implicits.scala

Answer (score 0):

In case you are willing to use Saddle, there's an implicit Datetime ordering defined there, in which case this is enough to solve the issue:

```
import org.saddle.time._
```