# How to define an Ordering in Scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, scala-collections

Having `val hm: HashMap[org.joda.time.DateTime, MyType]` I am trying to get the first and the last `DateTime` of the set by means of `hm.keys.min` and `hm.keys.max` respectively but the compiler says `No implicit Ordering defined for org.joda.time.DateTime`. How to define this ordering (both implicit and explicit options are interesting)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
object Joda {
    implicit def dateTimeOrdering: Ordering[DateTime] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_ isBefore _)
}

// elsewhere
import Joda._
dateTimes.sorted
```

Answer (score 17):

To facilitate working with Joda DateTime in Scala, nscala-time was created:
https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time

After including it in your project with

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0"
```

you can just import `OrderingImplicits`. Either all at once:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.OrderingImplicits._
```

or a particular one:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.OrderingImplicits.DateTimeOrdering
```