# Order by value in spark pair RDD after join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 paired RDDs that I joined them together using the same key and I now I want to sort the result using one of the values.
The new joined RDD type is :  RDD[((String, Int), Iterable[((String, DateTime, Int,Int), (String, DateTime, String, String))])]

where the first section is the paired RDD key and the iterable part is the values from the two RDD I joined. I want now to order them by the Time field of the second RDD. I tried to use sortBy function but I got errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Improve your question to get a quick and good answer.

Comment: Show your code, and the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Spark pair RDDs have a mapValues method. I think it will help you.

```
    def mapValues[U](f: (V) ⇒ U): RDD[(K, U)]
    Pass each value in the key-value pair RDD through a map function 
without changing the keys; this also retains the original RDD's partitioning.
```

[Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/api/core/spark/PairRDDFunctions.html) has more details.

Comment: not sure I understand how it helps me. can you explain more? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you can use `sortBy` function:

```
val yourRdd: RDD[((String, Int), Iterable[((String, DateTime, Int,Int), (String, DateTime, String, String))])] = ...(your cogroup operation here)

val result = yourRdd.sortBy({
  case ((str, i), iter) if iter.nonEmpty => iter.head._2._
  }, true)
```

`iter.head` has type of `((String, DateTime, Int,Int), (String, DateTime, String, String))`;

`iter.head._2` has type of `(String, DateTime, String, String)` and

`iter.head._2._2` is indeed has type of `DateTime`.

And maybe you should provide implicit ordering object for Datetime like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061141/how-to-define-an-ordering-in-scala).
By the way, may the iterator be emtpy? Then you should add this case to `sortBy` function. And if there are many items in this iterator which one to choose for sorting?

Comment: thanks @ipoteka, I still get errors.  this is the code I'm using:  val mappedDF = firstRDD.join(secondRDD).groupByKey()
    val res = mappedDF.sortBy(
        {case ((str, i), iter) if iter.nonEmpty => iter(0)._2._2}
        , true);  when standing on iter(0) the error is: Iterable[((String, DateTime, Int,Int), (String, DateTime, String, String))] does not take parameters Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It indeed may not have this method. But it must support `head` operation: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable So i edited my answer to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If the RDD's Iterable needs to be sorted:

```
val rdd: RDD[((String, Int), 
             Iterable[((String, DateTime, Int,Int), 
                       (String, DateTime, String, String))])] = ???

val dateOrdering = new Ordering[org.joda.time.DateTime]{ 
    override def compare(a: org.joda.time.DateTime,
                         b: org.joda.time.DateTime) = 
        if (a.isBefore(b)) -1 else 1
}

rdd.mapValues(v => v.toArray
                    .sortBy(x => x._2._2)(dateOrdering))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

```
sortedRDD = unsortedRDD.sortBy(lambda x:x[1][1], False)
```

This will sort by descending order