# Sorting a table by date in Slick 3.1.x

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I have the following Slick class that includes a date:

```
import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate

class ReportDateDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[ReportDateVO](tag, "report_dates") {

  def reportDate = column[LocalDate]("report_date")(localDateColumnType)

  def * = (reportDate) <> (ReportDateVO.apply, ReportDateVO.unapply)

  implicit val localDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, Date](
    d => Date.valueOf(d),
    d => d.toLocalDate
  )

}
```

When I attempt to sort the table by date:

```
    val query = TableQuery[ReportDateDB]
    val action = query.sortBy(_.reportDate).result
```

I get the following compilation error

> - not enough arguments for method sortBy: (implicit evidence$2: slick.lifted.Rep[java.time.LocalDate] ⇒
>     slick.lifted.Ordered)slick.lifted.Query[fdic.ReportDateDB,fdic.ReportDateDB#TableElementType,Seq].
>     Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
> - No implicit view available from slick.lifted.Rep[java.time.LocalDate] ⇒ slick.lifted.Ordered.

How to specify the implicit default order?

Comment: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/627 can help

Comment: I can't see how this can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `implicit val localDateColumnType` available where you run the query. For example, this will work:

```
implicit val localDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, Date](
  d => Date.valueOf(d),
  d => d.toLocalDate)

val query = TableQuery[ReportDateDB]
val action = query.sortBy(_.reportDate).result
```

I'm not sure where the best place to put this is, but I usually put all these conversions in a package object.

Answer (score 2):

It should work like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061141/how-to-define-an-ordering-in-scala):

```scala
implicit def localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_ isBefore _)
```

Comment: I added the implicit declaration right before the orderBy statement and still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I think my answer actually doesn't apply here. You could try putting localDateColumnType in a companion object and importing it in your client class.

Comment: what is localDateColumnType? how should I use it? can you post a code sample?

Comment: `localDateColumnType` is the column type value you used in your code example. Maybe it has to be visible in your client code, but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line to your import list:

**import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._**