# Sort by dateTime in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD[org.joda.time.DateTime]. I would like to sort records by date in scala.

**Input** - sample data after applying collect() below -

```
res41: Array[org.joda.time.DateTime] = Array(2016-10-19T05:19:07.572Z, 2016-10-12T00:31:07.572Z, 2016-10-18T19:43:07.572Z)
```

**Expected Output**

```
2016-10-12T00:31:07.572Z 
2016-10-18T19:43:07.572Z   
2016-10-19T05:19:07.572Z
```

I have googled and checked following link but could not understand it -

[How to define an Ordering in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061141/how-to-define-an-ordering-in-scala)

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you collect the records of your RDD, then you can apply the following sorting:

```
array.sortBy(_.getMillis)
```

On the contrary, if your RDD is big and you do not want to collect it to the driver, you should consider:

```
rdd.sortBy(_.getMillis)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define an implicit ordering for `org.joda.time.DateTime` like so;

```
implicit def ord: Ordering[DateTime] = Ordering.by(_.getMillis)
```

Which looks at the milliseconds of a DateTime and sorts based on that.

You can then either ensure that the implicit is in your scope or just use it more explicitly:

```
arr.sorted(ord)
```